# Failsafe move command

Tags: mv

Does a failsafe `mv` command exists?

Like a version of `mv` that does not overwrite without asking or just refuses if it has to overwrite

I don't talk about `mv` options but a way to have this failsafe per default in the mv command

Is there a package of mv with that? Or a conf file to reconfigure that? Or something?

Comment: Installing such a changed version of a standard command globally would probably break a whole lot of other things unexpectedly, for all users including root. You probably want to do this via a function defined only in your .bashrc profile.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the `mv` command with another one with a different behavior, or do you want another program with the different behavior? `mmv` is a good candidate, but I'd really go for the proposed alias in the answer below.

Comment: Not a changed version but a new command, with this failsafe

Comment: mmv has a failsafe per default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mmv` as suggested by @Quasímodo

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend aliasing the mv command in your `~/.bashrc` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) for the different login scripts and which one to use).

The code would look as follows:

```
alias mv="mv --no-clobber"
```

This would mean that whenever you used mv in your terminal, it would automatically (and invisibly) expand it to include the option.

Alternatively, you could use the `--interactive` flag (see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) for the difference between the options).